# How to use Tunisian Dinar currency in HTML?

Tags: javascript, html, currency-formatting

I need to show Tunisian Dinar(د.ت.‏) currency in HTML. I am getting the currency symbol as string from backend response.

I am able to display like number and then the currency symbol(د.ت.‏). Since it is arabic format the text comes from right to left so i am getting only the number first and the symbol next.

How can i show the symbol first and then the currency number.

Since i will be getting the currency symbol from backend response, i will not know whether that symbol is arabic or dollar or euro or something. So always i need to display the currency symbol first and then the currency number. There are no issues for other currency types. Since arabic format is from right to left i am facing this issue.

How can i achieve this.

Comment: html5 alone will not help you. There are specialized frameworks/libraries such as https://www.i18next.com/ that are meant to help with that.

Answer (score 0):

You use `bdo` tag in HTML to specify direction of the text , so for example `<bdo dir="rtl">4$</bdo>` it will displayed as `$4`

Ref : https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_bdo.asp

Comment: Since i am getting the symbol from backend i will not know whether the symbol is dollar or arabic currency. In javascript i am adding like "currency symbol + currency number" and displaying it in HTML. I should not directly put the string in reverse order.

Comment: @Keshav1007 Ok, you need to rephrase your question. explain all scenarios and how exactly you receive and display data.

Comment: Edited my question :)